# Issue when converting date and time different variables into dateTime variable

Tags: php

I have below code.

```
$DateDispatched = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', $Dat. ' ' . $Time);
```

> $Dat is 05/18/2009 
> $Tim is 08:37 AM

When I print it: `print_r($DateDispatched);` it always print false.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use format like this, and It it `$Tim` not `$Time`

```
  <?php
    $Dat = "05/18/2009 ";
    $Tim = "08:37 AM";

    $DateDispatched = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i A',$Dat.$Tim);

    print_r($DateDispatched);
  ?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/841805

Answer (score 0):

it's tested for you dear :

```
<?php
$Dat ='05-18-2009';
$Time = '08:37:44';
$DateDispatched = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s',$Dat.' '.$Time);
print_r($DateDispatched); 
?>
```

out put is :

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2009-05-18 08:37:44.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Kabul )
```

tested : https://3v4l.org/1GO3p

Comment: Check this : `/` is allowed http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$Dat = '05/18/2009';
$Tim = '08:37 AM';
$combine_string = $Dat."".$Tim;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($combine_string));
```